# 2d array in C with negative indices

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, free

I am writing a C-program where I need 2D-arrays (dynamically allocated) with negative indices or where the index does not start at zero. So for an array[i][j] the row-index i should take values from e.g. 1 to 3 and the column-index j should take values from e.g. -1 to 9.

For this purpose I created the following program, here the variable columns_start is set to zero, so just the row-index is shifted and this works really fine.

But when I assign other values than zero to the variable columns_start, I get the message (from valgrind) that the command "free(array[i]);" is invalid.
So my questions are:

1. Why it is invalid to free the memory that I allocated just before?
2. How do I have to modify my program to shift the column-index?

Thank you for your help.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{

int **array, **array2;
int rows_end, rows_start, columns_end, columns_start, i, j;

rows_start = 1;
rows_end = 3;

columns_start = 0;
columns_end = 9;

  array = malloc((rows_end-rows_start+1) * sizeof(int *));

  for(i = 0; i <= (rows_end-rows_start); i++) {
    array[i] = malloc((columns_end-columns_start+1) * sizeof(int));
  }

  array2 = array-rows_start;                          //shifting row-index

  for(i = rows_start; i <= rows_end; i++) {
    array2[i] = array[i-rows_start]-columns_start;    //shifting column-index
  }

  for(i = rows_start; i <= rows_end; i++) {
    for(j = columns_start; j <= columns_end; j++) {
      array2[i][j] = i+j;                             //writing stuff into array
      printf("%i %i %d\n",i, j, array2[i][j]);
    }
  }

  for(i = 0; i <= (rows_end-rows_start); i++) {
    free(array[i]);
  }

  free(array);

}
```

Comment: IMHO this is not good idea to make `pascal` from `C`

Comment: Is it possible to reduce this test case without making the error go away? For instance, is the second and third `for` loop necessary? Maybe the two `malloc` steps (for the outer and the inner arrays) plus the final `free` steps are already enough to trigger the valgrind warning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you shift column indexes, you assign new values to original array of columns: in

```
array2[i] = array[i-rows_start]-columns_start;
```

array2[i] and array[i=rows_start] are the same memory cell as array2 is initialized with array-rows_start.

So deallocation of memory requires reverse shift. Try the following:

```
free(array[i] + columns_start);
```

IMHO, such modification of array indexes gives no benefit, while complicating program logic and leading to errors. Try to modify indexes on the fly in single loop.

Comment: check the use of array/array2.

Comment: why is that? I don't see where `array` was shifted. Only `array2` points to a shifted place. `array` was never changed..

Comment: array2 points to array-rows_start. So array2[rowstart] == array[0]

Comment: free(array[i] + columns_start);
 This works, thank you very much.

Comment: @tyz, I updated your answer with your above comment.  It was what I missed in my (now deleted) answer and I guess the OP missed that as well.  And the edit allowed me to replace my downvote by an upvote.

Comment: @tyz: no you're right in your comment. But I still don't know why it has to be `free(array[i]+columns_start);`. array never changed its location.. only array2.

Comment: @duedl0r, Trying to explain in more detail. There is only one array in the memory. `array` and `array2` are pointers (and are used to modify the same piece of memory). When you change elements of `array2`, actually the elements pointed by `array` are also changed.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int a[] = { -1, 41, 42, 43 };
    int *b;//you will always read the data via this pointer
    b = &a[1];// 1 is becoming the "zero pivot"
    printf("zero: %d\n", b[0]);
    printf("-1: %d\n", b[-1]);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If you don't need just a contiguous block, then you may be better off with hash tables instead.

Comment: It would be great if you would actually provide more info about the actual problem.

Comment: No, this program solves a set of equations numerically. Simply speaking, I'm solving the equations at the points e.g. from 1 to 100, then I have boundary conditions first order at the points 0 and 101 and boundary conditions second order at the points -1 to 102.

Comment: I have to connect my code to an even bigger program which is written in C, so I'm restricted to this language. By the way, I already wrote my code in Fortran, there its really easy to create such arrays.

Comment: Ok, but at least accept my solution, since it solves the problem you've shown: negative index :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, your free and malloc looks good. But your shifting doesn't make sense. Why don't you just add an offset in your `array` instead of using `array2`:

```
int maxNegValue = 10;
int myNegValue = -6;

array[x][myNegValue+maxNegValue] = ...;
```

this way, you're always in the positive range.

For `malloc`: you acquire `(maxNegValue + maxPosValue) * sizeof(...)`

---

Ok I understand now, that you need `free(array.. + offset);` even using your shifting stuff.. that's probably not what you want. If you don't need a very fast implementation I'd suggest to use a struct containing the offset and an array. Then create a function having this struct and x/y as arguments to allow access to the array.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. An offset would be an idea, but im my program I need a lot of these arrays with all different beginning indices, so I hope to find a more elegant solution instead of defining two offsets for every array.          The sign is right I think, as I want to assign e.g. the value array2[1] to array[0].          Say, how can I rewrite the program without using array2?

Comment: I guess your valgrind problem is resolved. So you don't have to remove `array2`. Updated my answer with a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why valgrind would complain about that `free` statement, but there seems to be a lot of pointer juggling going on so it doesn't surprise me that you get this problem in the first place. For instance, one thing which caught my eye is:

```
array2 = array-rows_start;
```

This will make array2[0] dereference memory which you didn't allocate. I fear it's just a matter of time until you get the offset calcuations wrong and run into this problem.

One one comment you wrote

> but im my program I need a lot of these arrays with all different beginning indices, so I hope to find a more elegant solution instead of defining two offsets for every array.

I think I'd hide all this in a `matrix` helper struct (+ functions) so that you don't have to clutter your code with all the offsets. Consider this in some `matrix.h` header:

```
struct matrix; /* opaque type */

/* Allocates a matrix with the given dimensions, sample invocation might be:
 *
 *    struct matrix *m;
 *    matrix_alloc( &m, -2, 14, -9, 33 );
 */
void matrix_alloc( struct matrix **m, int minRow, int maxRow, int minCol, int maxCol );

/* Releases resources allocated by the given matrix, e.g.:
 *
 *    struct matrix *m;
 *    ...
 *    matrix_free( m );
 */
void matrix_free( struct matrix *m );

/* Get/Set the value of some elment in the matrix; takes logicaly (potentially negative)
 * coordinates and translates them to zero-based coordinates internally, e.g.:
 *
 *    struct matrix *m;
 *    ...
 *    int val = matrix_get( m, 9, -7 );
 */
int matrix_get( struct matrix *m, int row, int col );
void matrix_set( struct matrix *m, int row, int col, int val );
```

And here's how an implementation might look like (this would be `matrix.c`):

```
struct matrix {
  int minRow, maxRow, minCol, maxCol;
  int **elem;
};

void matrix_alloc( struct matrix **m, int minCol, int maxCol, int minRow, int maxRow ) {
  int numRows = maxRow - minRow;
  int numCols = maxCol - minCol;

  *m = malloc( sizeof( struct matrix ) );
  *elem = malloc( numRows * sizeof( *elem ) );
  for ( int i = 0; i < numRows; ++i )
    *elem = malloc( numCols * sizeof( int ) );

  /* setting other fields of the matrix omitted for brevity */
}

void matrix_free( struct matrix *m ) {
  /* omitted for brevity */
}

int matrix_get( struct matrix *m, int col, int row ) {
   return m->elem[row - m->minRow][col - m->minCol];
}

void matrix_set( struct matrix *m, int col, int row, int val ) {
   m->elem[row - m->minRow][col - m->minCol] = val;
}
```

This way you only need to get this stuff right once, in a central place. The rest of your program doesn't have to deal with raw arrays but rather the `struct matrix` type.